# MVC and Javascript/JQuery validation library

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, kendo-ui

I am working on a project that use MVC 2.0 with Kendo UI.  We decided to use AJAX  validation instead of MVC Model level validation; which means validation happens during most "onchange" events on HTML controls.  We coded the red CSS "highlight" on HTML controls when error happens and remove the highlight when there is no error.  If there are multiple controls (e.g. checkboxes) we will highlight all of them when error occurs...and of course, error messages related to multiple fields validaton....

We get it sort of working but we had to implement a lot of javascript/jQuery coding on each web form page (including control id/name matching on the validation message) and does not seem to be able to implement it as a common routine against all web forms.  We are also wondering if there is some sort of validation library already out there that more or less achieving the same thing...

Any suggestions?

Comment: there are lots of validation plugins...  did you try searching for them? Not hard to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tag your question with `kendo-ui` you are probably using it so it might be worthy taking a look into [`kendo.ui.Validator`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/validator)

Answer (score 1):

You should try [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Its very easy to use, but you do still need to link each input to they type of validation required